# Store & retrieve array in SQLite database in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wanted to store and retrieve an array in a SQLite database in my Xamarin App. I'm following this [Xamarin Tutorial on SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/local-database/?tabs=vswin).

These values will be then show in **Picker**. I used Models earlier to store array and then get the values and list it in **Picker**, it was working fine, but the only problem was that it wasn't stored permanently (by closing app array list get empty).

**Banks**

```
using SQLite;

namespace Mobile.App
{
    public class Banks
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Database.cs**

```
public class Database
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

    public Database(string dbPath)
    {
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<SQLiteBank>().Wait();
    }

    public Task<List<Banks>> GetBanksAsync(string name)
    {
        return _database.Table<Banks>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveBanksAsync(Banks bank)
    {
        return _database.InsertAsync(bank);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

Store and retrieve the array list in the database. When trying to save the array into the database, I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

When trying to retrieve the array from the database, I get an error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Mobile.App.Banks>' to 'string'

```
// Array of Bank Name and Number

string[] Name = new string[] { "Bank 1", "Bank 2", "Bank 3" };
string[] Number = new string[] { "000000", "111111", "222222" };

// Save it in database

await App.Database.SaveBanksAsync(new Banks
{
Name = Name, // Cannot implicity convert typer 'string[]' to 'string'
Number = Number // // Cannot implicity convert typer 'string[]' to 'string'
});

var bankName = await App.Database.GetBanksAsync(Name);

_bankList.Add(bankName); // Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Mobile.App.Banks>' to 'string'
```

And then get the values in **Picker**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _bankList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> BankList
{
    get
    {
        return _bankList;
    }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _bankList, value);
    }
}
```

```
<Picker 
    x:Name="picker_bank" 
    Title="Select Bank"
    ItemsSource="{Binding BankList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBank}">
</Picker>
```

Comment: what is `BankModel`?

Comment: **BankModel** is a model, `public static string[] Name { get; set; }`.. I can also use directly to initialize the array...

Comment: i edited it, changed it to `string[] Name` and `string[] Number`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of doing this

```
string[] Name = new string[] { "Bank 1", "Bank 2", "Bank 3" };
string[] Number = new string[] { "000000", "111111", "222222" };
```

try this

```
List<Banks> banks = new List<Banks>();

// repeat for each bank
banks.Add(new Banks { Name = "Bank1", Number = "00000" });
```

then you can save them to your db

```
foreach(var bank in banks)
{
    await App.Database.SaveBanksAsync(bank);
}
```

next, this doesn't work

```
var bankName = await App.Database.GetBanksAsync(Name);
```

because `GetBanksAsync` returns **all** banks, not just the name of one bank.

`BankList` should be an `ObservableCollection<Banks>`, not `string`.  Then you can do this

```
// load all banks into a list
var banks = await App.Database.GetBanksAsync();
// create an observablecollection from that list
BankList = new ObservableCollection<Banks>(banks);
```

Comment: thanks for response, now in **Picker**, there are 6 times `Mobile.App.Banks` is printed? and I just want to print the `Name` of Banks in **Picker**...

Comment: use the `ItemDisplayBinding` property to tell it which property of your model you want to display - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding

Comment: ok, thanks alot.. and if I want to **update** the number of specific bank e.g. `update the bank 10's number to 101010`.. how can I do this?

Comment: and can I open the sqlite file? and I can't find it, looked into `android/data`, there is nothing in there..

Comment: update the property on the appropriate Banks object and save it to the db - this is well documented