# In Xamarin SelectedItem in Picker is empty even after selecting a value

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin app, I'm loading banks information from database and trying to print the bank name in **Picker**.

It is working perfectly, [thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65749654/14515147).

There is also a button, which check if there is no value selected, it will be disable and on selecting a value from picker, it will become enabled.

When I was using a static values in Picker it was working perfectly, but now, as I'm loading bank list and printing it in Picker, after selecting the value from Picker, still the button is disabled.

**ViewModel.cs**

load all banks into a list

```
var getBanks = await App.Database.GetBanksAsync();

foreach (var item in getBanks)
{
    _bankList.Add(item);
}
```

And then get the values in **Picker**

```
private ObservableCollection<Banks> _bankList = new ObservableCollection<Banks>();
public ObservableCollection<Banks> BankList
{
    get
    {
        return _bankList;
    }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _bankList, value);
    }
}

private string _selectedBank;
public string SelectedBank
{
    get { return _selectedBank; }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedBank, value);
    }
}
```

*Button Code*

```
public ICommand SubmitCommand => new Command(async (submit) =>
{
    await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<SuccessViewModel>();
}, (x) => false);
```

**Views.xml**

*Pickers*

```
<Picker 
    x:Name="picker_bank" 
    Title="Select Bank"
    ItemsSource="{Binding BankList}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBank}">
</Picker>

<Picker 
x:Name="picker_country" 
Title="Select a Country"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}">
        <Picker.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Earth</x:String>
                <x:String>Mars</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

*Button Code*

```
<Button 
x:Name="SubmitButton"
Text="Submit"
IsEnabled="False"
Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding SelectedCountry,
                                   Converter={StaticResource stringNullOrEmptyValueBoolConverter }}" Value="false" />
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding SelectedBank,
                                   Converter={StaticResource stringNullOrEmptyValueBoolConverter }}" Value="false" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**UPDATE**

```
private Banks _selectedBank;
public Banks SelectedBank
{
    get { return _selectedBank; }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedBank, value);
    }
}
```

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is Banks bank && bank.Name == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: your Pickers contains a list of `Banks` so the selected value will be a `Banks` object, not a `string`

Comment: thanks for response.. I used `BankList = new ObservableCollection<Banks>(banks);` and in **Binding Properties**, I used `public string BankList` and it says **can't convert 'ObservableCollection' to 'string'**..

Comment: I just explained to you that `string` is not the correct type.  `SelectedBank` should be of type `Banks`

Comment: I did as u said, still same issue.. kindly, see the updated code..

Comment: you are using `stringNullOrEmptyValueBoolConverter` with a non-string type

Comment: yes, I updated the code above.. I changed `value is Banks bank` but can't write a correct statement to check if `Banks is IsNullOrEmpty` ?

Comment: `if (value is string` - you are still treating it like a string

Comment: as I said in above comment I tried `if (value is Banks` it's fine, but don't know, how check if `Banks IsNullorEmpty` like do in string?.. can u help with answer (code)?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+test+for+null+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: GREAT, Thanks.. if I select the values from Picker, it works, but app crash when I click on button, when no value is selected from Picker.. I updated the code, can u please have a look. and again thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use The following code

```
private Bank _selectedBank;
  public Bank SelectedBank
  {
  get { return _selectedBank; }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedBank, value);
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
private string _selectedBank;
public string SelectedBank
{
    get { return _selectedBank; }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedBank, value);
    }
}
```

Explaination : When you are using static value thats fine, because SelectedBank property is correctly maaping to a string type.But when are using Bank object from database to populate picker, you have to use the type as Bank for the SelectedBank Property.

and also change the use of `stringNullOrEmptyValueBoolConverter` because it will not serve your purpose when you are using Bank object as selectedBank.

change your StringNullOrEmptyValueBoolConverter like this

```
public class StringNullOrEmptyValueBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                if (value == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

## ***Ignore the above/previous solution***

First of all make your picker and button code like this

```
<Picker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
    x:Name="picker_bank" 
    Title="Select Bank"
    ItemsSource="{Binding BankList}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBank,,Mode=TwoWay}">
                        </Picker>

                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
x:Name="SubmitButton"
Text="Submit"
IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnable}"
Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"/>
```

now add IsButtonEnable property on your view model

```
protected bool _IsButtonEnable;
public bool IsButtonEnable
{
    get { return _IsButtonEnable; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _IsButtonEnable, value);
    }

}
```

on your selection change add this code

```
private Bank _SelectedBank;
        public Bank SelectedBank
        {
            get { return _SelectedBank; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedBank = value;
                if (SelectedBank != null)
                {
                    IsButtonEnable = true;
                }
                base.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedBank));
            }
        }
```

hope in this way you can meet your desired output. here i also have added a video link where you can see the output of my solution
[watch the video here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16LiT4ow0-1QfeBLTIfwQzleAP-vv5PJO/view?usp=sharing)

hope my effort will take you to your desired solution.thank you.

Comment: change the use of stringNullOrEmptyValueBoolConverter because it will not serve your purpose when you are using  Bank object as selectedBank. Because Bank object is not a string.

Comment: I updated the code above.. can u help? I can't check if `Banks is IsNullOrEmpty`...

Comment: If Pickers are empty (no value selected), by clicking on the **Button*, App crashed and says `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: and if Values are Selected in Picker (not empty), Button is still disabled..

Comment: answer is fully updated now and a video is attached.please watch the video and related changes on my code.hope it will help you :)

Comment: and one last thing, how can I make a check on multiple pickers? (as u see I have two pickers)

Comment: You have to make another property like selectedbank for your another picker.and then you have to check on set method for both the property. Like if(selectedbank!=null && selectedcountry!=null),inside this condition you have to put up your logic